# 'Uncaught SyntaxError:Cannot use import statement outside a module' when importing fs

Tags: javascript, import, fs

I am very green when it comes to JS, so I'm sorry if I'm asking a stupid question.
I tried to import fs using this code in my .js file:

```
import fs from 'fs';
```

and got 'Uncaught SyntaxError:Cannot use import statement outside a module' error in my **browser** console.
I also tried the 'old' way:

```
var fs = require ('fs');
```

but then got 'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at "higher_order_functions.js"'.
Additionally I tried adding type="module" to html as suggested when reading about similar problem:

```
<script type="module" src = "higher_order_functions.js"></script>
```

But then received 'Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "fs". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".' When I used one of these, then I got 404. And now I'm out of ideas.
Or is it just that I can't do it in browser?

higher_order_function.js looks like this:

```
import fs from 'fs';
var output = fs.readFileSync('data_reduce.txt', 'utf8');
console.log(output);
```

and .html like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Higher order functions </h1>
    <script type="module" src = "higher_order_functions.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can't use fs in a browser.

Comment: No `fs` in a browser